# Trouble with "Assembly File Selector" Dialog Box

Tags: c#

I am getting this error message on one of my development computers:

[image]

> Assembly File Selector
> The following assembly name can not be resolved automatically.
> System.XML, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
> Please select the assembly file manually.

The error is happening on a new computer I just setup. This error does not happen on any of the other computers I have used my program on.

The program uses .NET Framework 4.8. I have installed that framework on this computer. I am both building my program and running it on this computer.

Nothing I do with the dialog box seems to matter. My program works fine if press OK or cancel. Selecting a file does not prevent the dialog from appearing again.

I assume there's some configuration step that didn't happen right on this new computer. What can I do to track down what is going wrong?

Comment: A Net application will only run if the build and deploy machines have same version of Net installed.  Otherwise you have to publish application and then run setup.exe on deploy machine to get code working.  You can check installed version of Net by check in Control Panel : Software to see list of software installed.  I suspect on existing machines different version of Net are installed.  Old version of Net you have to install all previous versions like 1.0, 2.0, 3.5, 4.0.  New versions of Net you only have to install latest.  Old machine probably have 2.0 installed and new doesn't.

Comment: I updated the post to clarify that I am building and deploying on the same computer using .NET Framework 4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem thanks to hints from Mitch and Simon Mourier.

My specific application is an add-in for a program called Revit. During development, I use another add-in to load my add-in. I was using an older version of the other add-in. For whatever reason, on this specific computer, it was throwing this error. I am using the same old add-in on other computers with no problems.

I replaced the other add-in with the most recent version and it works correctly.

I looked at the referenced for the old add-in. I referenced the latest version of System.Xml (4.0.0.0). There were no references to System.XML version 1.0.0.0. I never did track down why that was specifically being ask for.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very old version of System.Xml - .Net 4.8 would have version number 4.0.0.0.  If you are not intended to use an older version of .Net, verify your references are not set to "Use Specific Version" and that your project is targeting .Net 4.8.

That dialog looks like something from Redgate Reflector, which implies you are working with existing assemblies.  In that case, you might check the version of the reference in Reflector to confirm.

Do you have the same versions of the older frameworks installed?

Comment: Not sure a System.XML (uppercase) w/o a strong name (PublicKeyToken=null) ever existed. Something is weird here.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Good point.  Didn't catch that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. They were able to get me moving in the right direction. I solved the problem by upgrading another program on my computer. I never did figure out where that System.XML reference was really coming from.